# How do I show the contents of a matrix?

Tags: forth, gforth

Consider:

```
: cell-matrix
 create ( width height "name" ) over , * cells allot
 does> ( x y -- addr ) dup cell+ >r @ * + cells r> + ;
```

It is the definition that makes the matrix and then you assign values like this:

```
 5 5 cell-matrix test
```

And then you stuff the values into there.... There they're...

```
36 0 0 test !
```

(I think)

Nowhere on the Internet can you find anything to explain this. How do you show the contents of the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print the contents of the whole matrix, you can do something like:

```
: .row ( addr u -- addr' u ) tuck 0 do @+ . loop swap cr ;
: .matrix ( u addr -- ) >body @+ rot 0 do .row loop 2drop ;
```

Note that your `cell-matrix` doesn't save the number of rows, so you have to supply this number to `.matrix`.  E.g. like this:

```
2 3 cell-matrix foo
3 ' foo .matrix
```

Answer (score 2):

Logically simple:

```
100 0 0 test !   ok
400 1 0 test !   ok
0 0 test @ .     100 ok
1 0 test @ .     400 ok
```

Comment: Note that `@ .` can be replaced with `?`.